# Better way of writing json files in C# and validate the code

Tags: c#, json

i have a lass like this

```
    public class Params
    {
        public string FirstName;
        public string SecondName;
        public string Path;
        public long Count;
        public double TotalSize;
        public long Time;
        public bool HasError;

        public Params()
        {

        }
        public Params(string firstName, string secondName, string path, long count, double totalSize, long time, bool hasError)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            SecondName = secondName;
            Path = path;
            Count = count;
            TotalSize = totalSize;
            Time = time;
            HasError = hasError;
        }
}
```

I have the json class like this:

```
    public static class FileWriterJson
    {
        public static void WriteToJsonFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = true) where T : new()
        {
            TextWriter writer = null;
            try
            {
                var contentsToWriteToFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite);
                writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
                writer.Write(contentsToWriteToFile);

            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();
            }
        }

        public static T ReadFromJsonFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
        {

            TextReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContents);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

The main program is like this

```
 var Params1 = new Params("Test", "TestSecondName", "Mypath",7, 65.0, 0, false);
 FileWriterJson.WriteToJsonFile<Params>("C:\\Users\\myuser\\bin\\Debug\\test1.json", Params1);
 FileWriterJson.WriteToJsonFile<Params>("C:\\Users\\myuser\\bin\\Debug\\test1.json", Params1);
```

This is mine test1.json:

> {"FirstName":"Test","SecondName":"TestSecondName","Path":"Mypath","Count":7,"TotalSize":65.0,"Time":0,"HasError":false}{"FirstName":"Test","SecondName":"TestSecondName","Path":"Mypath","Count":7,"TotalSize":65.0,"Time":0,"HasError":false}

As you can see i have two json objects written in the file.

What i need to do is:

```
void ReadAllObjects(){
//read the json object from the file
 // count the json objects - suppose there are two objects 
for (int i=0;i<2;i++){ 
//do some processing with the first object 
// if processing is successfull delete the object (i don't know how to delete the particular json object from file) 
 } }
```

but when i read like this

```
var abc =FileWriterJson.ReadFromJsonFile<Params>(
                            "C:\\Users\\myuser\\bin\\Debug\\test1.json");
```

i get the following error:

> "Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {.
>   Path '', line 1, position 155."

Then i used the following code to read the JSON file

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FromDelimitedJson<T>(TextReader reader, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
{
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) { CloseInput = false, SupportMultipleContent = true })
    {
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);

        while (jsonReader.Read())
        {
            if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
                continue;
            yield return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Which worked fine for me.

> Now i need following suggestion:

1> when i put my test1.json data in https://jsonlint.com/ it says Error:

```
Parse error on line 9:
    ..."HasError": false} { "FirstName": "Tes
    ----------------------^
    Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
    should i write into file in some other way.
```

> 2>Is there any better of doing this.

Comment: You have multiple json in the same file. Without an array structure around them. That's not the standrad, you should try to write a collection with all your item.

Comment: Or you will need a separator that is impossible in the file. EG if you use new lines, one json per line,  you can do something like `var result = File.ReadAllLines("path\to\file.txt").Select(line =>  JsonDeserialize<YourClass>(line)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You are writing each object out individually to the file.
But what you are creating is not a valid JSON file, just a text file with individual JSON objects.

To make it valid JSON, then you need to put the objects into an array or list and then save this to the file.

```
var Params1 = new Params("Test", "TestFirstName", "Mypath",7, 65.0, 0, false);
var Params2 = new Params("Test 2", "TestSecondName", "Mypath",17, 165.0, 10, false);

List<Params> paramsList = new List<Params>();
paramsList .Add(Params1);
paramsList .Add(Params2);

FileWriterJson.WriteToJsonFile<List<Params>>("C:\\Users\\myuser\\bin\\Debug\\test1.json", paramsList);
```

FileWriterJson.WriteToJsonFile("C:\Users\myuser\bin\Debug\test1.json", Params1);

Then you should be able to read it in OK.  Don't forget to read in a `List<Params>`